# PHP Email On iPhone Not Displaying Correctly

Tags: php, iphone, email

I have a form that sends an email to the website owner and the form submitter. It looks great everywhere but on an iPhone it includes all of the html code.

Here is my code to process the form:

```
 <?php

 $name_field = $_POST['name'];
 $email_field = $_POST['email'];
 $phone = $_POST['phone'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];
 $link = $_POST['link'];
 $to = 'me@me.com';
 $toCust = $email_field;
 $subject = 'Lead From Website';
 $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
 $headers = "From: me@me.com\r\nReply-To: $email; ";
 $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-".$random_hash."\"";
 ob_start();
 ?>


 --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?> 
 Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit


 <h3>Contact Form Submission From Website</h3>
 <table width="39%" cellpadding="10" border="0">
   <tr>
     <td width="47%"><strong>Name:</strong></td>
     <td width="53%" style='color:#990000'><?php echo $name_field; ?></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><strong>Email:</strong></td>
     <td style='color:#990000'><?php echo $email_field; ?></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><strong>Phone Number:</strong></td>
     <td style='color:#990000'><?php echo $phone; ?></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><strong>Message:</strong></td>
     <td style='color:#990000'><?php echo $message; ?></td>
   </tr>

 </table>

 --PHP-alt-<?php echo $random_hash; ?>--
 <?
 $message = ob_get_clean();
 if(isset($_POST['link']) && $_POST['link'] == ''){


     $mail_sent = @mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );
$mail_sent = @mail( $toCust, $subject, $message, $headers );
header('Location: thankyou.html');
 }
 echo $mail_sent ? "Your email has been sent." : "The message failed to send. Our form thinks   you're spam. If you're not, please give us a call";
 ?>
```

and here is was I get on my iPhone as plain text:

```
--PHP-alt-1962a6e1cb0d62a23c8e1743bd157401 
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<html>
<body>
<h3>Contact Form Submission From Website</h3>
<table width="39%" cellpadding="10" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="47%"><strong>Name:</strong></td>
    <td width="53%" style='color:#990000'>Dave</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Email:</strong></td>
    <td style='color:#990000'>me@me.com</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Phone Number:</strong></td>
    <td style='color:#990000'>666-666-6666</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Message:</strong></td>
    <td style='color:#990000'>test of iphone</td>
  </tr>

</table>
</body>
</html>
--PHP-alt-1962a6e1cb0d62a23c8e1743bd157401--
```

Answer (score 0):

You problem is likely here:

```
 Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
```

UTF-8 and 7bit encodings are pretty much mutually exclusive seeing as UTF-8 is a multibyte encoding. You should probably switch to quoted-printable and use [`quoted_printable_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.quoted-printable-encode.php). There are drop-in replacements in the comments if you're using PHP < 5.3.

### edit

```
$part_header = <<<_EOI_

 --PHP-alt-$random_hash
 Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

_EOI_;

$part_body = <<<_EOI_
 <html>
 <body>
 <h3>Contact Form Submission From Website</h3>
 <table width="39%" cellpadding="10" border="0">
   <tr>
     <td width="47%"><strong>Name:</strong></td>
     <td width="53%" style='color:#990000'>$name_field</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><strong>Email:</strong></td>
     <td style='color:#990000'>$email_field</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><strong>Phone Number:</strong></td>
     <td style='color:#990000'>$phone</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td><strong>Message:</strong></td>
     <td style='color:#990000'>$message</td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 </body>
 </html>

 --PHP-alt-$random_hash--
 _EOI_;

$message = $part_header . quoted_printable_encode($part_body);
```

Comment: Hi Sammitch, I checked out the documentation on the quoted_printable_encode() and its a little above my level. It looks like I just wrap the whole thing in a function. Does that apply to my code as well? Thanks! Dave

Comment: @FTSoR it should only be applied to the body of the MIME part, not the headers. I've updated my answer with some code that replaces the output buffering with [HEREDOCs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc), and splits the header and body sections into their own parts. While I was writing, however, I noticed that you've also omitted the `<html>` and `<body>` tags which could also be the reason why the iPhone mail client doesn't render the message properly.

Comment: It's funny you say that. Adding those tags was the first thing I tried with no luck. Thanks for the update. I'll give it a shot.